# Nullable struct vs class

Tags: c#, .net

I have a simple struct which contains two fields; one stores an object and the other stores a DateTime. I did this because I wanted to store objects in a Dictionary but with a DateTime stamp as well.

I've got a method which returns my structure, and I've now decided the method should also be able to return null, so I made my structure nullable. I'm now wondering if I should just make my structure a class so it's a reference type?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this case, yes, it's probably clearer to make your structure a class.

As far as justification goes, you're essentially creating a specialized `Tuple`.  It's interesting to note that the library designers have opted to make the [.Net 4 `Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(VS.100).aspx) a class rather than a struct.  (That page is the tuple creator and links to the various tuple instance classes)

Comment: The "tuple as a class" is probably mainly to keep things consistent when you get to Tuple<,,,,,,,> (8 args) - which would almost certainly be oversized as a struct - especially if any of the T are non-trivial.

Comment: @Marc: That's a good point.  I hadn't noticed until just now that the Tuples are immutable.

Answer (score 6):

Either should be fine, in reality (as long as the `struct` is immutable). A `DateTime` and a reference shouldn't be enough to make it oversized.

I assume you are using it as the *value* (not the *key*) in the dictionary? If used as the key you would need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode()`, regardless of `struct` vs `class`.

Comment: Yep, am using it as value, not key, so am overriding those methods.

Comment: (maybe I didn't phrase it well... those methods are only important [in this context] when used as a key)

Comment: Yes, I understand - not needed for me. You mean if you're using the class as a key, as someone explained in one of the answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689940/hashtable-with-multidimensional-key-in-c