# What datastructure should I use?

Tags: c#, data-structures

I have an issue where I need to map two inputs to a single output.

I'm aware that a dictionary is a generically typed linear mapping:

> for every x (`key`) there may be a y (`value`)

What I need is a multi-dimensional mapping:

> for every x,y (`key`) there may be a z (`value`)

But of course the kicker is that I need it to support generic typing and be dynamically sized.

Does this data-structure exist in C#, or do I have to create a dictionary of dictionaries? I'd rather not reinvent the wheel if I don't have to.

---

### Reinventing the wheel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace zlib.Collections
{
    public class Dictionary3D<Tx, Ty, Tz>
    {
        private Dictionary<Tuple<Tx, Ty>, Tz> _dict = new Dictionary<Tuple<Tx, Ty>, Tz>();

        public void Add(Tx x, Ty y, Tz z)
        {
            _dict.Add(Tuple.Create<Tx, Ty>(x, y), z);
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            _dict.Clear();
        }

        public bool ContainsKey(Tx x, Ty y)
        {
            return _dict.ContainsKey(Tuple.Create<Tx, Ty>(x, y));
        }

        public bool ContainsValue(Tz z)
        {
            return _dict.ContainsValue(z);
        }

        public Dictionary<Tuple<Tx, Ty>, Tz>.Enumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            return _dict.GetEnumerator();
        }

        public bool Remove(Tx x, Ty y)
        {
            return _dict.Remove(Tuple.Create<Tx, Ty>(x, y));
        }

        public bool TryGetValue(Tx x, Ty y, out Tz z)
        {
            return _dict.TryGetValue(Tuple.Create<Tx, Ty>(x, y), out z);
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get { return _dict.Count; }
        }

        public Dictionary<Tuple<Tx,Ty>,Tz>.KeyCollection Keys
        {
            get
            {
                return _dict.Keys;
            }
        }

        public Dictionary<Tuple<Tx, Ty>, Tz>.ValueCollection Values
        {
            get
            {
                return _dict.Values;
            }
        }

        public Tz this[Tx x, Ty y]
        {
            get
            {
                return _dict[Tuple.Create<Tx, Ty>(x, y)];
            }
            set
            {
                _dict[Tuple.Create<Tx, Ty>(x, y)] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems like reinventing the wheel is winning out among responses. This is the code I've come up with so far, but I feel like there should be a better way, like a `matrix` or something.

Comment: is the type of key the same for both x and y? can you explain how you need generic typing for a key? heterogeneous key?

Comment: @DarthVader, the type for the keys could be the same in some circumstances, but it wont always be.

Comment: I suppose i should also specify, the type of the key will be specific to the instance of the multi-dimensional object. Ideally I'd be able to write `new Dictionary3D<Foo,Bar,Baz>();` and have it work just as well as `new Dictionary3D<int,int,bool>();`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689940/hashtable-with-multidimensional-key-in-c-sharp, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171812/multi-key-dictionary-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what about

```
   Dictionary<Tuple<T,K>,Tuple<L,J>>
```

??

Comment: After messing around with creating a custom class that acted as a wrapper, I decided that it really wasn't worth it for the little bit of code needed to create new `Tuples`.

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right, that is what you need:

```
class Key<Tx, Ty>
{
    public Tx x;
    public Ty y;

    public Key(Tx x, Ty y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

Dictionary<Key<Tx, Ty>, Tz> d;
```

And yes, how mentioned in a comment, you gotta implement HashCode and Equals in that Key class.

Comment: Ouch, sorry, didn't know about that.

Answer (score 1):

**Tuple** is probably what you want:

```
var population = new Tuple< string, int>("New York", 7891957);
```

or for generics:

```
var population = new Tuple< S, T>("New York", 7891957);
```

For *Tuple* a reference look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx)

Moreover, if you want for example user Dictionary of a Dictionary you can do like this:

```
using DictOfDict = Dictionary< X, Dictionary< Y, Z>> ;
```

For a reference look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c/74482#74482)

Answer (score 1):

The PolyDictionary that Chuck Jazdzewski wrote about awhile back might get you what you want if you use a Tuple<T1, T2> as the key. Really, it's just a wrapper around a Dictionary<object, object> but it does the trick. Check out his blog series on the topic:

- [PolyDictionary](http://www.removingalldoubt.com/PermaLink.aspx/a2934e63-8a08-4fcf-9f5b-88ba1f50f7c7)
- [PolyDictionary II: Constructed Keys](http://www.removingalldoubt.com/PermaLink.aspx/195f76e3-a734-4502-8fd6-6d2e49f2e4e3)
- [PolyDictionary III: Cast away](http://www.removingalldoubt.com/PermaLink.aspx/d378c798-718d-4fab-b42c-f14da5edb6de)
- [PolyDictionary IV: By extension](http://www.removingalldoubt.com/PermaLink.aspx/3f5c7a8d-2574-43b5-aafc-acfc3cd66b7c)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
class Dict3D
{
    private Dictionary<KeyValuePair<object,object>, object> innnerDict= new Dictionary<KeyValuePair<object,object>, object>();

    public object Get(object key1, object key2)
    {
        KeyValuePair<object,object> bigKey = new KeyValuePair<object, object>(key1, key2);
        if (innnerDict.ContainsKey(bigKey))
        {
            return innnerDict[bigKey];
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void Set(object key1, object key2, object somevalue)
    {
        KeyValuePair<object, object> bigKey = new KeyValuePair<object, object>(key1, key2);
        if (innnerDict.ContainsKey(bigKey))
        {
            innnerDict[bigKey] = somevalue;
        }
        else
        {
            innnerDict.Add(bigKey, somevalue);
        }
    }
}
```

You could make it a generic also, but this is a simple version.

I guess the answers mean that if you want a clean solution, you (or someone else) probably does have to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need a type safe heterogeneous container, which is backed by a dictionary. In this case, you will have to override IDictionary and have your own impl. Unfortunately there is no class that you can use unless you follow other answers or find a work around i guess.

See [Joshua bloch](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA142&lpg=PA142&dq=type%20safe%20heterogeneous%20container&source=bl&ots=yYDoKhr3RZ&sig=FV1JQdXamTe4TL2XanZdcESQxzU&hl=en&ei=XOyhToKpJseuiALHpJnbBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=type%20safe%20heterogeneous%20container&f=false) in this case, you can basically store any type as the key. however you can restrict that as well.