# One Key to multiple values dictionary in C#?

Tags: c#

I often need one key to multiple vaules dictionary, but in C# most of them are two dimensions like Dictionary and Hashtable.

I want something like this:

```
var d = new Dictionary<key-dt,value1-dt,value2-dt,value3-dt,value4-dt>();
```

dt inside<> means data type. Anybody has ideas about this?

Comment: I'm assuming you want a key value pair with the value being a list? It's valid to do: `var d = new Dictionary<string, List<object>>();` or whatever you want to store a list of.

Comment: You'll need to explain what you want a bit better. The current explanation doesn't really say anything. Give an example of how you might use the dictionary you envision.

Comment: The Dictionary requires 2 Arguments so what is it you are ultimately trying to achieve here..?

Comment: Thanks Justin, you are right.it dosen't show correctly here due to some special charactores in my content.

Comment: What is the key of your dictionary? The string? Or everything but the last argument?

Comment: See this similar question for some ideas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689940/hashtable-with-multidimensional-key-in-c-sharp

Comment: So many down votes? It's not a bad question, it's just a duplicate.

Comment: @GertArnold It is a bad question because it's entirely ambigous as to what he wants.  Does he expect a multi-keyed dictionary, a dictionary with one key and multiple values, does he expect multiple keys *and* multiple values, etc.  He did not respond to the clarifying questions and instead left the question as is despite lots of confusion.  That's a poor quality question.

Comment: using Tuple as the value part in Dictionary is whay i want.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A dictionary is a key-value pair, where the value is fetched depending on the key. The keys are all unique.

Now if you want a `Dictionary` with 1 keytype and multiple value types, you have a few options:

first is to use a `Tuple`

`var dict = new Dictionary<KeyType, Tuple<string, string, bool, int>>()`

The other is to use (with C# 4.0 and above):

`var dict = new Dictionary<KeyType, dynamic>()`

the `System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject` can have value of any type.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test {
   public static void Main(string[] args) {
        dynamic d1 = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
    var dict = new Dictionary<int, dynamic>();
        dict[1] = d1;
        dict[1].FooBar = "Aniket";
        Console.WriteLine(dict[1].FooBar);
        dict[1].FooBar = new {s1="Hello", s2="World", s3=10};
        Console.WriteLine(dict[1].FooBar.s1);
        Console.WriteLine(dict[1].FooBar.s3);
   }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain this one `dict[1] = d1;
        dict[1].FooBar = "Aniket";`? as I understood `dic[1].FooBar = Aniket` is the key for dictionary, but what does `FooBar` in that case mean?

Comment: @vladimir the `.FooBar` in this case means it can be anything at all. You can take the same code and replace `.FooBar` with `.vladimir` and it would still work. I have dynamically, at runtime, created a property in `dict[1]` (which points to `d1`)  called `FooBar`

Comment: can we initialize DICT out of method as global variable e.g   `  <string, dynamic>  { "Sweden", currentRate = 9.95 },
            { "Sweden", currency = "SEK" } `

Comment: this is a great solution. kinda turns C# into javascript. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Describe both the appropriate key fields and the appropriate value fields with **classes.** and use a dictionary of those types.

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<TheKeyType, TheValuesType>();
```

Note: If you have multiple values acting as the key, you would define a class to encapsulate those values and provide proper overrides of GetHashCode and Equals so that the dictionary could recognize their equality.

Short of doing this, you can utilize tuples, but you want to limit this pattern, as tuples are non self-describing.

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<Tuple<Key1Type, Key2Type, Etc>, Tuple<Value1Type, Value2Type, Etc>>();
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using a Tuple, which is a perfectly valid solution, i'd advise on creating your own class as the key and/or Value.

You might realize the tuple will become an hard to read code.

Comment: With the caveat that he would have to implement Equals() and GetHashCode() manually.

Comment: @SystemDown: Thanks for pointing it out. One most decide for the trade offs

Comment: @SystemDown That's only true if the custom class is the key; if it's the value that's not needed.

Comment: Please create your own class, don't use Tuple it's extremely unmaintainable.

Comment: Nowadays with named tuples my answer can be considered outdated

Answer (score 1):

Use a [tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) as a key.

```
var d = new Dictionary<Tuple<string,string,bool,int>,any-data-typs>();
```

Comment: I would suggest rather using one of those types as key, and Tuple<...> as value.

Comment: Thank you, this is what i want. I will use it like this:
var d = new Dictionary<string,Tuple<string,string,bool,int,any-data-typs>>();

Comment: @LukaszM - the way I understood it was that he wanted a composite key.

Comment: @Giswin - If what you want is a composite key, then this will work. It could get a bit ugly as tuples are not self-describing though.

Comment: I see. I suppose he just wanted a collection that associates together more than two values. Anyway, `Tuple` class can be used in both cases :).

Comment: Yes, in my case because I want a one key to multiple values data set, 
var d = new Dictionary<string,Tuple<string,string,bool,int,any-data-types>>(); 
This is what i want.

Comment: Yep, don't use a Tuple for the key, just the value. Because it's what the OP wanted anyway.