# Object or Tuple?

Tags: c#, object, tuples

I was searching for a solution for the problem I'm having in my project.
In the link below I found something usefull:

[One Key to multiple values dictionary in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987156/one-key-to-multiple-values-dictionary-in-c)

However: isn't it better to use a Object in the dictionary instead of using a Tuple??

```
Object obj = new Object();
var dict = new Dictionary<KeyType, obj>();
foreach(KeyType kt in dict)
{
  obj.X = value1;
  obj.Y = value2;
}
```

Instead of:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<KeyType, Tuple<string, int, int, int>>()
```

I hope that there is someone who could help me. Thanks :)

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile. `obj.X` doesn't exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do `obj.X` in C#, if `obj` is of type `Object`. But you can create a custom class *derived from `Object`*, which contains all the field and properties you need and use it inside the dictionary.

This would indeed be superior to the `Tuple` solution, since `myObj.Speed` is much more descriptive than `myTuple.Item2`.

Note, however, that `Tuple`s have some features that your custom class might not have, for example, `tuple1.Equals(tuple2)` returns true if both have the same elements. With your custom class, `Equals` will check for reference equality, unless you override it.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not better to use `object` - you loose your strong typing.

If you are concerned about the verbosity of your code, you can always do something like this:

At the top of your document:

```
using MyDictionary = Dictionary<KeyType, Tuple<string, int, int, int>>;
```

Then your constructors do this:

```
var dictionary = new MyDictionary();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Tuple I prefer to make a simple class with two/three fields. It's much cleaner solution and it's easier to use.