# SignalR concurrent list best practice

Tags: c#, signalr

I'm using SignalR in a c# MVC web application. I want to have a list of objects ( UserDetail ) of the current form authenticated users. this object should hold the UserId ( Pk from table ) and ConnectionId ( SignalR ).

Today I'm using a static list in the hub class :

```
public static List<UserDetail> ConcurrentUsers = new List<UserDetail>();
```

And handle remove from list and insert to list in each of the Hub events

```
public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
{
     if (ConcurrentUsers != null && ConcurrentUsers.Any(x => x.ConnectionId.Equals(Context.ConnectionId)))
          ConcurrentUsers.Remove(ConcurrentUsers.Find(x => x.ConnectionId.Equals(Context.ConnectionId)));
     return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
}

public override Task OnConnected()
{
     IsUserAuthenticated();
     return base.OnConnected();
}

public override Task OnReconnected()
{
     IsUserAuthenticated();
     return base.OnReconnected();
}

private void IsUserAuthenticated()
{
     if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.User != null &&  HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
     {
           var user = DalHelper.GetUserNoTracking(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
           if (user == null)
           {
                 Clients.Caller.GoToLogin();
                 return null;
           }


           if (!ConcurrentUsers.Any(x => x.ConnectionId.Equals(Context.ConnectionId)))
           {
               UserDetail ud = new UserDetail { 
                  ConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId,
                  UserId = user.UserId,
               };
               ConcurrentUsers.Add(ud);
           }

      }
      return null;
}
```

When I want to update a user with his data, let's say a new message he received I then can go over the list and find all the connectionId's of that user and push the message to all the connected User clients.

```
private static void FlushMessageToClient(Guid UserId, string Message)
{
    string[] cids = Hub.ConcurrentUsers.Where(x => x.UserId.Equals(UserId)).Select(x => x.ConnectionId).ToArray();
    foreach (string cid in cids)
    {
        Hub.Clients.Client(cid).messageReceived(Message);
    }
}
```

All is working good until the web site runs for an hour with in and out users ,It will start to receive errors :

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object. at Infra.ChatHub.b__16(UserDetail
>   x) at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2
>   predicate) at ChatHub.IsUserAuthenticated()

Is there a better way to program it ?

Comment: The problem is that you are updating (.Add) while itrerating the collection (.Where). You either need to use locks or change to thread safe collections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can find the best option under
Mapping SignalR Users to Connections.

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections

Answer (score 0):

I would use a dictionary if you have a key index:

```
Dictionary<Guid, UserDetail > dictionary = new Dictionary<Guid, UserDetail >();
```

You can do:

```
dictionary.Add(userId, userDetail);   
var detail = dictionary[userId];
```

About your error, check that the userId is in the list before query it.

```
if (dictionary.ContainsKey(userId)) {}
```

Comment: Please take in mind that each UserId has many ConnectionId , User can logon from different tabs / browsers . so I will need a fast reliable access to all connectionId's given UserId and vise versa.

Comment: Ok (I thought userId was a key, as said in question). You can then use a struct (userId, connectionID) as a key. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689940/hashtable-with-multidimensional-key-in-c-sharp.

Comment: UserId is key but can have more then 1 connectionid.