# Asset Type how to make a list of key value pairs

Tags: c#, xml, xna

I recently was saving data in a dictionary using XNA XML content

```
<Asset Type="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[System.String, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector2]">
```

The dictionary works, but it doesn't allow me to save duplicate keys. So now I want to use a List of key value pairs. I tried the following:

```
<Asset Type="System.Collections.Generic.List[KeyValuePair[System.String, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector2]]">
```

However, this doesn't work. Does Anybody know how to correctly do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hashtable with MultiDimensional Key in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689940/hashtable-with-multidimensional-key-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I have removed tag(s) from your question's title based on  _[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)_ where the consensus is **no** _they should not_.