# Dictionary with Tuple key in Powershell

Tags: powershell, dictionary, tuples

I need to create a Dictionary with Tuple key in Powershell.
Exactly like I can do in C# like this:

```
var test = new Dictionary<(int, bool), int>();

// Add
test.Add((1, false), 5);

// Get
int a = test[(1, false)];
```

(Taken from [Hashtable with MultiDimensional Key in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689940/hashtable-with-multidimensional-key-in-c-sharp))

Is it possible? (I am running Powershell version 5.1.18362.145.)

Thanks!

Comment: You can explicitly create a `Tuple` or `ValueTuple` in PowerShell (`$x = @{ [System.ValueTuple]::Create(1, $false) = 5 }; $x[[System.ValueTuple]::Create(1, $false)]`), but since there's no syntactic sugar for it and PowerShell's support for generics is a little spotty, it's not a particularly nice experience. I suppose you could wrap the `Create` in a local function with a short name. Note that PowerShell's own custom objects act "weird" when used as keys since PowerShell doesn't automatically add proper hashing and equality support, so those aren't attractive alternatives either.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert, I'll try it out!

The note about hashing and equality support I _think_ will be no problem for me, because the resulting Dictonary will be sent to an API with C# code.

Comment: Hashing and equality support is always relevant, regardless of language, because `Dictionary` (and `Hashtable`, which PowerShell uses) use it to look up and store keys. `ValueTuple` has support for this, so they are suitable as dictionary keys, but PowerShell's custom objects do not (not by default, anyway).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add to [Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert)'s excellent comments on the question:

The following is a **direct translation of your C# code** to PowerShell v5.1+ code:

```
using namespace System.Collections.Generic

# Construct
$test = [Dictionary[[ValueTuple[int, bool]], int]]::new()

# Add
$test.Add([ValueTuple[int, bool]]::new(1, $false), 5)

# Get
$test[[ValueTuple[int, bool]]::new(1, $false)]
```

- `using namespace` is a PSv5+ feature akin to C#'s `using` construct: it allows you to refer to the types in the specified namespace by their mere names, without namespace qualification.
- As Jeroen points out, **PowerShell has no syntactic sugar for value-tuple instances**, so that C# tuple literal `(1, false)` must be represented as an explicit constructor call: 
  `[ValueTuple[int, bool]]::new(1, $false)`.

  - The alternative is to use the static [`Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.ValueTuple.Create) method on the non-generic `System.ValueType` base type, in which case the tuple component types are *inferred*:
    `[ValueTuple]::Create(1, $false)`

---

Given that PowerShell exposes a type's constructors via the static `::new()` method on the type itself, you can **simplify the code by instantiating the specific tuple type once and reusing it via a variable** (ignore the broken syntax highlighting):

```
using namespace System.Collections.Generic

# Instantiate the concrete tuple type (type arguments locked in).
$tupleType = [ValueTuple[int, bool]]

# Construct the dictionary with the tuple type as the key.
# See explanation below.
$test = [Dictionary`2].MakeGenericType($tupleType, [int])::new()

#`# Add
$test.Add($tupleType::new(1, $false), 5)

# Get
$test[$tupleType::new(1, $false)]
```

The downside is that the dictionary construction becomes more awkward, because PowerShell type literals such as `[Dictionary[[ValueTuple[int, bool]], int]]` must not have non-literal components.
To work around that, [`System.Type.MakeGenericType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Type.MakeGenericType) is used to construct the closed generic type from the dynamically specified type arguments; note the need to specify the arity (`` `2 ``) of the open generic type on which `.MakeGenericType()` is invoked.